# Getting equations to show in html

Tags: r, tex

Using knitR in RStudio.I have the following code in my document

`$$GKTM = \frac{\sum_{t=1}^{n} (Engine_t)_{gallons}}{(Tonnage_{kilotons})(Distance_{miles})} $$`

When I hit "Knit HTML", everything comes up as desired and the Rieman sum 'E' appears as desired. However, when I save the Knit HTML output to my desktop and open it, it does not show the nicely formatted equation as desired but the Latex code above. What is wrong.

I don't think I entered a heading into my RStudio knitr file. The top of my document starts with this:

````
```{r, echo = FALSE}
#  Loads data that you'll call in knitR
load("C:/Users/m5mkx/Documents/work/123.RData")
data_path <- '~/work/leader/reports/data/2016-01-22/'
load(file = paste(data_path, 'etl.raw.RData', sep='')) 
```
````

To check and see if a header would fix the problem, I inserted the following at the top of the document:

```
---
title: "Unexplained trend deviations in GKTM values over time"
output:
 html_document:
  mathjax: local
  self_contained: false
---
```

When I hit "Knit HTML", the header above prints out like this at the top of the HTML preview document (all on one line):

```
title: “Unexplained trend deviations in GKTM values over time” output:     
   html_document: mathjax: local self_contained: false
```

and my equation is not rendered correctly. I'm new to knitR and have only been working with it a couple of days. I'm sure there is an easy quick fix to my problem.

Comment: What does your document header look like? `knitr` relies on `MathJax` for equation rendering in HTML, (some more info [here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#mathjax_equations)), so if you are changing the defaults to, say, make a non-self-contained document that could throw things off. Also, what browser are you using when you open the HTML file?

Comment: I'm no longer at work so I cannot check the header. The default browser is IE. Could you provide the correct document header? Thanks.

Comment: The default header should work fine. I was just make sure you hadn't edited it.